# "sending 'const NSString *' to parameter of type 'NSString *' discards qualifiers" warning

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, warnings, constants

I have Constants NSString, that I want to call like:

```
[newString isEqualToString:CONSTANT_STRING];
```

Any wrong code here?

I got this warning:

> sending 'const NSString *' to parameter of type 'NSString *' discards qualifiers

How should these be declared?

Comment: how are these strings defined ?

Answer (score 956, accepted):

You should declare your constant string as follows:

```
NSString * const kSomeConstantString = @""; // constant pointer
```

instead of:

```
const NSString * kSomeConstantString = @""; // pointer to constant
// equivalent to
NSString const * kSomeConstantString = @"";
```

The former is a constant pointer to an `NSString` object, while the latter is a pointer to a constant `NSString` object.

Using a `NSString * const` prevents you from reassigning kSomeConstantString to point to a different `NSString` object.

The method `isEqualToString:` expects an argument of type `NSString *`. If you pass a pointer to a constant string (`const NSString *`), you are passing something different than it expects.

Besides, `NSString` objects are already immutable, so making them `const NSString` is meaningless.

Comment: You said the former is the constant pointer to an NSString object. So that means the pointer is constant. Hence I can't reassign that to another NSString.

Comment: I wish I could give you ten upvotes! Thank you for your understandable and very helpful answer!

Comment: how in the earth NSString * const is a const pointer to NSString? What's their context free grammar generator?

Comment: @Jim the problem is in you not having learnt C properly, don't blame it on others. The `const` qualifier applies to the term on its left, and it applies to the term on its right only if there's nothing on its left side (e. g. `const char *` and a `char const *` are non-const pointers to const char, but `char *const` is a const pointer to non-const char).

Comment: +1.  And +1000 for *"Besides, NSString objects are already immutable, so making them const NSString is meaningless."*

Comment: Thank you @albertamg.  I'd like to add that using #define MACRO string constants in ternary operations produces compiler error, but static NSString * const kMyConst @"CONSTANT_VALUE"; works perfectly well in ternary operations, as such: control.text = (controlActivated==YES) ? mKConst : @"Activate Me";

Comment: Nowadays, Xcode sometimes gives a warning if you don't cast the constant string... "(NSString *)".  Easy enough.

Comment: "NSString is already immutable. So making them const is meaningless". Actually, you can reassign them. That's the issue for me.

Comment: @PatrickBassut making the NSString const is meaningless but making the pointer to the NSString const is NOT. That is the point of the answer.

Comment: "making the pointer to the NSString const is NOT" meaning that if you use `NSString * const kSomeConstantString` it cannot be reassigned?

Comment: Also, for static const you should use:  *static NSString *const*

Answer (score 6):

just to put all on one place which found on various post on stackoverflow and works for me , #define is bad because you cannot benefit from variable types, basically the compiler replaces all occurrence when compiles (import Constants.h whenever you need) :

```
//  Constants.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Constants : NSObject

extern NSString *APP_STATE_LOGGED_IN;
extern NSString *APP_STATE_LOGGED_OUT;
@end

// Constants.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Constants.h"

@implementation Constants

NSString *APP_STATE_LOGGED_IN  = @"APP_STATE_LOGGED_IN";
NSString *APP_STATE_LOGGED_OUT = @"APP_STATE_LOGGED_OUT";
@end
```

Answer (score 6):

spare few minutes to read this. A goodread on pointers hell on constants and vice-versa.

http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html