# Error SIGBART in XCode iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a program with different components, but when I compile, I get signal SIGBART every time. The main purpose of my code is to change a boolean when the user moves, set text to a variable when a button is tapped, and set a string to do/don't with the press of different buttons. My code is below:

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize mapView;
@synthesize dodont;
@synthesize reminders;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    on = @"don't";
    dodont.text = on;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
didUpdateUserLocation:
(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    move = TRUE;
}

- (IBAction)enable:(id)sender {
    on = @"do";
}

- (IBAction)disable:(id)sender {
    on = @"don't";
}
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    content = reminders.text;
}
@end
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

NSString *on;
BOOL move= FALSE;
NSString *content;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    MKMapView *mapview;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

- (IBAction)enable:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)disable:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dodont;
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *reminders;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

Comment: Where in your code does the `SIGABRT` occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you want to put this stuff:

```
NSString *on;
BOOL move= FALSE;
NSString *content;
```

between `@interface` and `@end` in your .h file?

And don't forget for: `@property (nonatomic, strong)` for each property (BOOL value have no strong parameter).

Your interface should look like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    MKMapView *mapview;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *on;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL move;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *content;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *reminders;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dodont;

- (IBAction)enable:(id)sender;    
- (IBAction)disable:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender;

@end
```

Comment: Those are globals, and this should be a comment.

Comment: So, you do it wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808159/objective-c-global-variables

Comment: I'm still getting SIGBART

Comment: return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,     NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

Comment: I changed the variable declaration and simplified it, I'll paste the new code on paste bin

Comment: If you want, you may send whole project to me, I'll find mistake faster.

Comment: Sure thing. Let me upload it

Comment: The download link is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/010buqwj2aswgmk/Oops%2C%20I%20Forgot.zip

Comment: Open your storyboard. Open view controller's connections. You'll find there connections to 2 objects, but they have been deleted. Delete this connection (you'll see "!"-symbol there).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. =)

Answer (score 0):

In iOS/Objective-C, variables should be declared like below given way :

@interface Classname:SuperClass

{

- #Declare variables here

}

- ## Set property for variables here
- ## declare methods here

@end

And you are declaring the variables above the class declarations.

Also you haven't initialized the window for the application in applicationdidFinishLaunching method. Try this and setting the window rootviewcontroller with the view you want to load.

Comment: I think he uses storyboards.. so this isn't matter.