# How to add value in NSMutableArray when button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c

for my iOS app I want to initiate an NSMutableArray and change the Object the array holds during runtime with buttons. So far I was able to initiate an array in viewDidLoad {} in the ViewController.m but now i can't access it in my buttonPressed method. How can I make the array accessible for the hold file?

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSMutableArray *toCalculate = [@[@0] mutableCopy];
}


- (IBAction)numbersButtonsPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"%ld\n", sender.tag);
    [toCalculate addObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:sender.tag]];
}
```

Comment: Please put your code in the question, not as a screenshot. You need to declare your array as a property, not a local variable in `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare variable as global(class variable) not in local variable(function).

[What is global variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808159/objective-c-global-variables)

Solution for the problem is:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){
    NSMutableArray *toCalculate;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    toCalculate = [@[@0] mutableCopy];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}



- (IBAction)numbersButtonsPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@",toCalculate);
    [toCalculate addObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:sender.tag]];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Paul,
it work like he said if you implement it as a @property in the ViewController.h file.

```
   @interface ViewController: UIViewController

   @propety NSMutableArray *giveItAName

   @end
```