# iOS: Mistake with "Constants.h"

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have declared a constant header file : "Constants.h". It contains the declarations below:

```
extern const NSString   *Const_alertPayantMessage = @"test";
extern const NSString   *Const_alertPayantTitle   = @"Wooooops!!!";
extern const int        *Const_statutPayant       = 1;
```

And I used this constants in this way:

```
int x = 1;

    if (x == Const_statutPayant) {
        UIAlertView* mes=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:Const_alertPayantTitle
                                                    message:Const_alertPayantMessage delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [mes show];
        [avPlayerError play];
    }else{
        [avPlayer play];
```

Unfortunately, I can not run my application because I have this error message:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Have you got any idea?

Comment: Mark's answer is correct.  But might I suggest that you avoid using capital letters at the start of your variable names, from a coding standards point of view, it is often advised to start variables with a lower case letter so that they are quickly and easily distinguished from classes

Comment: In fact, I do not know the programming standards in Xcode. Each language has its peculiarities. Thx you for your additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Constants.h" should contain:

```
extern const NSString   *Const_alertPayantMessage;
extern const NSString   *Const_alertPayantTitle;
extern const int        Const_statutPayant;
```

"Constants.m" should contain:

```
const NSString   *Const_alertPayantMessage = @"test";
const NSString   *Const_alertPayantTitle   = @"Wooooops!!!";
const int        Const_statutPayant       = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **Constant.h** should be like

```
NSString   *  const kAlertPayantMessage;
NSString   *  const kAlertPayantTitle;
```

And your **Constant.m** should be like

```
NSString   *  const kAlertPayantMessage = @"test";
NSString   *  const kAlertPayantTitle   = @"Wooooops!!!";
```

[Why you have to use **NSString* const** instead of **const NSString *** ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828831/sending-const-nsstring-to-parameter-of-type-nsstring-discards-qualifier/6830983#6830983)

Comment: I will change with:

NSString   *  const kAlertPayantMessage = @"test";

Thx you.